# How to find xarray values that are present in a list?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a list of nonzero numbers (`blob_numbers_126_list`) that I want to compare to a fairly large dataarray.

```
blob_numbers_126 = blobs_126.where(icemask_126_regrid[30,:,:] == 1).data.flatten()
blob_numbers_126 = blob_numbers_126[~np.isnan(blob_numbers_126)]
blob_numbers_126_list = list(set(blob_numbers_126[blob_numbers_126!=0]))
```

I am currently trying to use xr.where() to compare the dataarray(time,lat,lon)(`blobs_126`) to the list. If the value in the data array is present in the list I want it to make that cell 1, otherwise I want it to be 0.

Here is what I currently have:

```
blobs_126_source = blobs_126.where(blobs_126[:,:,:].data == any(np.array(blob_numbers_126_list)),1,0)
```

And this gives

```
xarray.DataArray'ar_binary_tag'time: 44521lat: 192lon: 288
array([[[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        ...,
...
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]]], dtype=int32)
Coordinates:
time
(time)
float64
-1.34e+07 -1.34e+07 ... -1.313e+07
lat
(lat)
float64
-90.0 -89.06 -88.12 ... 89.06 90.0
lon
(lon)
float64
0.0 1.25 2.5 ... 356.2 357.5 358.8
Indexes: (3)
Attributes: (0)
```

I was expecting a binary array with a 1 where the value in the dataarray was found in the list and a 0 when the value wasn't present in the list. However I just get a full array of 1's.

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Just one think I saw `blobs_126[:,:,:]` is the whole array. `any(np.array(blob_numbers_126_list))` will likely be always a scalar True value and you compare your whole array it, not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `any(np.array(blob_numbers_126_list))` will return `True` if there's **at least one nonzero** number in `blob_numbers_126_list` and `False` otherwise. That's why your output array consists entirely of 1's.

You can use the `np.isin()` function, which tests whether each element of an array is also present in a second array, and returns a boolean array. Try this one:

```
blobs_126_source = xr.DataArray(np.isin(blobs_126.data,blob_numbers_126_list).astype(int), coords=blobs_126.coords)
```